# Count occurrences of int in array java

Tags: java

I have an array stored as:

```
 static int[] number = new int[50];
```

I want to write a piece of code that will count how many times certain ints appear in the array. Say the number 1.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: have you tried writing any code.

Answer (score 5):

In that case I suggest you trying doing that. Start with a simple example, add a loop to iterate over the array and count the number of occurances. At the end print the answer.

A next step would be to make the "countOccurances" a method which takes the array, the value searched for and returning the number of occurances.

BTW: I wouldn't make the array static unless you cannot avoid it.

If you want a specific answer, I suggest asking a specific question regarding code you have written including what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: So why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: You will get better responses if you look like you are looking to learn and asking for help on something you have attempted.  Posters which don't make an effort often don't even bother reading or replying to the answers given which just annoys people. Some people looking to cheat on their homework don't even bother to google to see if the answer is already available on the web ;)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your array on a loop and check with if, increase your counter.

Comment: You should not have done that. He tried nothing to solve his problem himself.

Comment: @Quoi, your code is obviously correct. However don't you think that posting your answer you are encouraging people asking questions instead of thinking?